# How to reset short animation before you meet the NPC for a first time

Tags: black-desert-online

The First time I was playing BDO I was rushing through the NPC interactions because I wanted to catch up with my friend's level, so I mostly focus on the grind.  However now that we are the same level I want to start with a new character to experience the story side of this game.

However I noticed that when I play with new character the short introduction clip that played when you meet some NPC for a first time, for example when you meet with skill instructor in Olvia is not playing. I know they are not relevant but they are nice touch and since I am playing with new character I wanted to experience the story of the game as a whole.

Does anyone know is it possible to restart it for brand new characters or even for all of them?